# When a permutation matrix is desired for transforming camera frame to world frame?

Tags: matrices, transformation, change-of-basis

When dealing with rectified images, why would the inverse of a simple permutation matrix $$P =
{\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}$$
is sufficient to transform coordinate in camera frame to world frame, such that $X_w = P * X_c$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: First of all, the matrix that you have written is not a permutation matrix. Second, it would be helpful if you could provide context: presumably, $X_w,X_c$ denote the world-frame coordinate vector and camera-frame coordinate vector, but this should be stated explicitly. It is obviously incorrect to say that these coordinates satisfy the relation $X_2 = P X_c$ for **every** camera orientation. Please explain the exact conditions under which this relationship is supposed to hold, or at least tell us where you encountered this equation